# Transactionの検索について

Tags: ethereum

PrivateNetで開発しています
特定(自分だったりコントラクトであったり)のアドレスから送った履歴を一覧にする方法について

Block No.を順に検索し、Transaction No.が含まれていたらそのTransactionのFromだったりToだったり、場合によってはInputを参照すると考えて実装しました
4000Block中5件のTransactionを見つけるだけで４０分ぐらいかかりました
他に高速にできる方法・ライブラリがあれば情報いただけないでしょうか
Gethのコマンドは確認しましたが、前述の方法以外思いつかない状況です
検索のプログラムはAWS LambdaでPythonを使って開発しています

直接携わっていないのですが、Bitcoinで開発した際の類似機能ですと、`RPCOperations.listtransactions`に近いかと思います

Answer (score 0, accepted):

外部データベースにインデックスを作成しておく方法が考えられます。
あらかじめ外部データベースに特定のアドレスが関連するトランザクションのトランザクションIDを保存しておき、参照する場合はデータベースに保存されているIDを利用することで高速化することができます。

Comment: ご指摘の通りDB使うしかなさそうですね。規模が大きくなると承認数も確認して再格納とか必要になりそうで頭が痛いですが、やってみます。